# How can I structure and recode messy categorical data in R?

Tags: r, statistics, plyr

I'm struggling with how to best structure categorical data that's messy, and comes from a [dataset](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BypDSvtB33v7MjQ0OTBmYjQtMjBlYy00MDJjLWJmZmQtMjkxM2VhMDNmMGFl&hl=en) I'll need to clean.

#### The Coding Scheme

I'm analyzing data from a university science course exam. We're looking at patterns in
student responses, and we developed a coding scheme to represent the kinds of things
students are doing in their answers. A subset of the coding scheme is shown below.

[image]

Note that within each major code (1, 2, 3) are nested non-unique sub-codes (a, b, ...).

#### What the Raw Data Looks Like

I've created an anonymized, raw subset of my actual data which you can view [here](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BypDSvtB33v7MjQ0OTBmYjQtMjBlYy00MDJjLWJmZmQtMjkxM2VhMDNmMGFl&hl=en).
Part of my problem is that those who coded the data noticed that some students displayed
multiple patterns. The coders' solution was to create enough columns (`reason1`, `reason2`,
...) to hold students with multiple patterns. That becomes important because the order
(`reason1`, `reason2`) is arbitrary--two students (like student 41 and student 42 in my
[dataset](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BypDSvtB33v7MjQ0OTBmYjQtMjBlYy00MDJjLWJmZmQtMjkxM2VhMDNmMGFl&hl=en)) who correctly applied "dependency" should both register in an analysis, regardless of
whether `3a` appears in the `reason` column or the `reason2` column.

#### How Can I Best Structure Student Data?

Part of my problem is that in the [raw data](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BypDSvtB33v7MjQ0OTBmYjQtMjBlYy00MDJjLWJmZmQtMjkxM2VhMDNmMGFl&hl=en), not all students display the same
patterns, or the same number of them, in the same order. Some students may do just one
thing, others may do several. So, an abstracted representation of example students might
look like this:

[image]

Note in the example above that `student002` and `student003` both are coded as "1b", although I've deliberately shown the order as different to reflect the reality of [my data](http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BypDSvtB33v7MjQ0OTBmYjQtMjBlYy00MDJjLWJmZmQtMjkxM2VhMDNmMGFl&hl=en).

#### My (Practical) Questions

1. Should I concatenate `reason1`, `reason2`, `...` into one column?
2. How can I (re)code the `reason`s in R to reflect the multiplicity for some students?

#### Thanks

I realize this question is as much about good data conceptualization as it is about specific features of R, but I thought it would be appropriate to ask it here. If you feel it's inappropriate for me to ask the question, please let me know in the comments, and stackoverflow will automatically flood my inbox with sadface emoticons. If I haven't been specific enough, please let me know and I'll do my best to be clearer.

Comment: Just realized in my graphic above that I mislabeled the fourth student as "student003" as well. D'oh! :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it "long":

```
library(reshape)
dnow <- read.csv("~/Downloads/catsample20100504.csv")
dnow <- melt(dnow, id.vars=c("Student", "instructor"))
dnow$variable <- NULL ## since ordering does not matter
subset(dnow, Student%in%c(41,42)) ## see the results
```

What to do next will depend on the kind of analysis you would like to do. But the long format is the useful for irregular data such as yours.

Comment: Frequency of each response `table(dnow$value)`, and "which students had a particular response?" `with(dnow, sort(Student[value == "3a"]))` might be good starting questions for an analysis.

Comment: @Eduardo - Thanks so much! I've never seen the `%in%` syntax before. What does it do?

Comment: @Richie - Thanks for your comments, and your patience! This is my first big data analysis. While I have a sense of what research questions are emerging ("do the frequencies of particular answer patterns vary by instructor?"), I'm not always sure how to instantiate them in R syntax.

Comment: briandk - `%in%` is basically a binary interface to `match()`, which you can actually look up with ?match (unlike ?%in%).  Basically, you give it a vector of values on the left and a vector of values on the right, and it will give you a logical vector indicating which of the values in the left-hand vector are in the right-hand one.  In Eduardo's code, it's giving `subset()` a vector of TRUE and FALSE to indicate which rows are students 41 and 42.

Comment: @Matt: You can get help on `%in%` by quoting it, like so `?"%in%"`, though in this case it takes you to the same page as `?match`.

Comment: @briandk: You'll want something like `with(dnow, tapply(value, instructor, table))`, or visually (using `ggplot2`) `ggplot(subset(dnow, value != ""), aes(value)) + geom_bar() + facet_grid(instructor ~ .)`.

Answer (score 2):

you should use ddply from plyr and split on all of the columns if you want to take into account the different reasons, if you want to ignore them don't use those columns in the split. You'll need to clean up some of the question marks and extra stuff first though.

```
x <- ddply(data, c("split_column1", "split_column3" etc),
           summarize(result_df, stats you want from result_df))
```

Answer (score 1):

What's the (bigger picture) question you're attempting to answer? Why is this information interesting to you?

Are you just trying to find patterns such as 'if the student does this, then they also likely do this'?

Something I'd consider if that's the case - split the data set into smaller random samples for your analysis to reduce the risk of false positives.

Interesting problem though!

Comment: @Stray - Thanks! Your suggestion's well-taken. My research questions are still in the formative stages, but one thing I plan to do is compare student performance by instructor, and answer patterns by instructor. Most of my early comparisons will involve [ANOVA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anova) and sadly splitting my dataset will kill the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) on it.